# How to convert time String into NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How can I convert time string (in 24h format) into NSDate for comparison?

I get nil and wrong NSDate here:

```
let a = "5:46"
let b = "24:30"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "k:mm" // k = Hour in 1~24, mm = Minute

let outputA = dateFormatter.dateFromString(a)
let outputB = dateFormatter.dateFromString(b)

println("A: \(outputA)  B: \(outputB)")
```

Then I get

```
A: Optional(1999-12-31 20:46:00 +0000)  B: nil
```

when I wish to get

```
A: 5:46 AM  B: 00:30 AM
```

or

```
A: 05:46  B: 24:30
```

It doesn't really matter which NSDate format as long as I can compare those two hours.

Comment: Do you want to get hour and minutes separately?

Comment: I have added an answer. It's work for you or not? @Joon. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `NSTimeZone` in date formate.

```
    let a = "5:46"
    let b = "24:30"

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "k:mm" // k = Hour in 1~24, mm = Minute
    let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.timeZone=timeZone
    let outputA = dateFormatter.dateFromString(a)
    let outputB = dateFormatter.dateFromString(b)

    println("A: \(outputA)  B: \(outputB)")
```

**Output is :**

```
Printing description of outputA:
2000-01-01 05:46:00 +0000
Printing description of outputB:
2000-01-01 00:30:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three completely different questions here:

1. Why does the first date look wrong?

   You are getting `20:46` for the first date because `5:46am` in your local time zone is equal to `20:46 GMT` (that's what the `+0000` means, GMT+0). So don't worry about that it *looks* different. The simple truth is that 5:46am in your local timezone *is* 20:46 GMT+0.

   People frequently recommend specifying the formatter's `timeZone` to GMT/UTC. In my opinion, that's a fundamentally flawed approach. That works, but it suggests a misunderstanding of the underlying issue, that `NSDate` objects do not have an inherent concept timezone. If you want to show a time in a current time zone, you always use a formatter. I'm presuming that when you say 5:46am, you mean 5:46am where the user actually is located, rather than 5:46m in London.

   Clearly, if when you say 5:46, you really meant 5:46 GMT (i.e. in London), then fine, set the timezone to be GMT. You'll do that a lot with Internet date formats like RFC 3339 or ISO 8601, where we do consciously change everything to GMT for consistency's sake. But if that's not the case, I think it's better to let the formatter use the default `timeZone` (your current timezone) and just be aware that `NSLog`/`print` will always show the time in GMT and know that when you want to show the time in the app, always use a formatter to properly format it for your local time zone.
2. Why is the second date `nil`?

   This one is a bit of a mystery. Your formatter is wrong (you should use either `dateFormat` or `timeStyle`/`dateStyle`, but not both), but I don't think that's the problem. The use of `24:30` is a little curious to US eyes (we'd generally use `00:30`), but I guess its not unheard of in UK, China, Japan, and Hong Kong, etc. Plus you're using `k:mm`, so I would have thought that it would have accepted `24:30`. The `k:mm` formatter string worked fine for me, though.

   Bottom line I cannot reproduce the `nil` behavior you describe. Perhaps you can tell us what locale you're using and use just `dateFormat`, but not `timeStyle`.
3. Why are the output times not formatted properly?

   If, having parsed the original strings to `NSDate` objects, if you want to create a new output string in some predetermined format, then you'd *use another formatter* for converting that `NSDate` back into a string in the desired format.

   ```
   let a = "5:46"
   let b = "24:30"

   let inputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   inputFormatter.dateFormat = "k:mm" // k = Hour in 1~24, mm = Minute

   let dateA = inputFormatter.dateFromString(a)
   let dateB = inputFormatter.dateFromString(b)

   println("dateA: \(dateA)  dateB: \(dateB)")

   let outputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   outputFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle

   let stringA = outputFormatter.stringFromDate(dateA!)   // these only work if the date is not `nil`
   let stringB = outputFormatter.stringFromDate(dateB!)

   println("stringA: \(stringA)  stringB: \(stringB)")
   ```

   On my computer, that outputs:

   > dateA: Optional(2000-01-01 10:46:00 +0000)  dateB: Optional(2000-01-01 05:30:00 +0000)
   >
   > stringA: 5:46 AM  stringB: 12:30 AM

   The dates are those times are correctly parsed into `NSDate` objects (which output their value in GMT, `+0000`) and then reconverted to output strings per whatever style/format you provide.

Clearly, this assumes you fix the issue with `dateB` being `nil`. Please provide more information regarding your configuration and/or provide us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code for the your problem.

```
let a = "5:46"
    let b = "24:30"
    let dtf = NSDateFormatter()
    dtf.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dtf.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let date : NSDate = dtf.dateFromString(a)!
    let date1 : NSDate = dtf.dateFromString(b)!
    println("\(date)","\(date1)")
```

Note: If you are using 24 hour time format then u don't need to take "24:30" and NSDate object will never give you only time. it will always return date also if you will use the format which i mentioned in above code.